# Sending user enter value to another program using named pipe

Tags: c, communication, named-pipes

In my program, I want to send user enter value "select1" to another program using a named pipe "pipeselect". When I run my program and enter 1, the program is on hold and cannot print "Option 1 is selected". What's wrong with my program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
 char pipeselect[] = "/tmp/pipeselect";
 char bufs[2];
 int fds;
 int select1;

 /* Pipe Creation */
 if (access(pipeselect, F_OK) == -1) {
  fds = mkfifo(pipeselect, 0700);
  if (fds != 0) {
   printf("Pipe creation error\n");
   exit(1);
  }
 }

  printf("1. Option 1\n");
  printf("2. Option 2\n");
  printf("Please select an option: ");
  scanf("%d", &select1);
  int i = select1;

  switch(i) {  

   case 1: 
   if ((fds = open(pipeselect, O_WRONLY)) < 0) {
    printf("Pipe open error\n");
    exit(1);
   }
   bufs[0] = i;  
   write(fds,bufs,1);
   close(fds);

   printf("Option 1 is selected\n");
   break;

   case 2: 
   if ((fds = open(pipeselect, O_WRONLY)) < 0) {
    printf("Pipe open error\n");
    exit(1);
   }
   write(fds,bufs,i);
   close(fds);

   printf("Option 2 is selected\n");
   break;

   default:
   printf("Wrong Input!\n");
   break;

 unlink(pipeselect);
 exit(0);

 }
}
```

Comment: How many times have you executed your program? Because you don't actually remove the pipe from the file-system, so anytime you execute your program and select an option you will write to the pipe, and sooner or later the pipe will become full and writing to it will block. Try to remove the pipe and run again.

Comment: From mkfifo man(3) : "However, it has to be open at both ends simultaneously before you can proceed to do any input or output operations on it. Opening a FIFO for reading normally blocks until some other process opens the same FIFO for writing, and vice versa."

Comment: Oh... you wake me up and appreciate for this